# Does the linux bridge have in-built DHCP and DNS server?

Tags: domain-name-system, linux-networking, bridge, dhcp-server, virtual-network

Does the linux bridge have a dhcp server built in to the bridge software?

And does the linux bridge support working as DNS-Server or it can only point towards the DNS server on the host or none. If none, then how does the VM's connected to the linux bridge resolve hostnames?

Answer (score 2):

In general the Linux/Unix way is to build tools and solutions that do one thing  really well and then use other existing tools and products to provide other complementary/ related functionality.

The Linux bridge only bridges.

VM’s either get their settings by DHCP from the network the bridge connects them to, or maybe they are set directly from whatever tool you use  to create the vm

A common helper tool by the way is dnsmasq

Comment: well, i was looking it in docker context. So from your response what I infer is: Docker provides a DHCP server along with creating a bridge network: `docker0` bridge network for containers to connect. @HernanB, please inform me if I got it wrong.?

Comment: Although Docker daemon assigns IP addresses to containers, it is not a real DHCP server.